# Replace string value with txt file content C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've been working on a project lately & I'm totally new to .NET so excuse me for that -.-

I was wondering how to replace the value of a string with the content of a .txt file.
This is what I've got so far but it won't work -_- Instead of showing me the content of the file it shows me the path as I wrote it.

```
string replacedString = string1.Replace(string1, Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\scripts\StickyNotes\Server Website.txt");
```

The `string1` was in fact a string array that I converted. But I don't think this should make any difference because it's equal to a string now. Btw this string contains now a value equal to 1 line of text. So what the .txt file should do is overwriting that line with the new value.

Maybe there isn't a direct option to do that so what I'm asking you is maybe a little complicated -.-

Because I'm new to C# coding could you also explain what the code of your answer is supposed to do xP

Thanx for taking your time!!

*Edit: I also wan't to note that I'm actually working in a `public StickyNotes()`. So no static class.*

Comment: so you don't care about the value of string1 anymore? or you want to replace something inside of string1 with the file contents?

Comment: Yes @MichaelSharp

Comment: I don't care about the values in the string1 just wan't to replace them with the file contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just do `string replacedString = File.ReadAllText(@"\scripts\StickyNotes\Server Website.txt");` This will read in the file, and create a new variable called `replacedString` to store the file contents.

If you want to overwrite string1, then assign the return value from `File.ReadAllText` to that instead of creating a new variable `replacedString`. It would look like this `string1 = File.ReadAllText(@"\scripts\StickyNotes\Server Website.txt");`

`File.ReadAllText()` Takes in the path of the file you want to read, and then returns the whole file as a string. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

the `string.Replace()` method you were using, "Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) Essentially, it looks for the first value you passed in, and replaces it with the second one.

Comment: But this won't overwrite the content of my string1 right?

Comment: It can do either depending on which variable you assign the results to. I wasn't sure if you wanted to overwrite it or not, which is why I explained both.